# TCP C# Client and Server by BinaryWriter/Reader

Tags: c#, tcp

I have to do 2 simple programs that one of them is the server(only receiving) and the other is client(only sending). 
My trying code : 
**Server :**

```
// Definition for TCP connection with simulation Radar
private TcpClient c;
private NetworkStream n;
private BinaryReader reader;
public static TcpListener listenerForRadarLocation;

// Definition for sendRadarLocation message
private string nameOfRadar;
private UInt32 typeOfRadar;
private UInt32 AzimuthStart;
private UInt32 AzimuthEnd;
private UInt32 Alt_flag;
private UInt32 LongRadar;
private UInt32 LatRadar;
private UInt32 Zaltitude;
private UInt32 Range_min;
private UInt32 Range_max;
private UInt32 Azimuth;
private UInt32 HighAzimuth;

//In button received click event :
listenerForRadarLocation = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 43, 145 }), 1300);
listenerForRadarLocation.Start();
using (c = listenerForRadarLocation.AcceptTcpClient())
{
    using (n = c.GetStream())
    {
        reader = new BinaryReader(n);
        nameOfRadar = reader.ReadString();
        typeOfRadar = reader.ReadUInt32();

        AzimuthStart = reader.ReadUInt32();
        AzimuthEnd = reader.ReadUInt32();

        Alt_flag = reader.ReadUInt32();

        LongRadar = reader.ReadUInt32();
        LatRadar = reader.ReadUInt32();

        Zaltitude = reader.ReadUInt32();
        Range_min = reader.ReadUInt32();
        Range_max = reader.ReadUInt32();
        Azimuth = reader.ReadUInt32();
        HighAzimuth = reader.ReadUInt32();
    }
}
```

**Client :**

```
private TcpClient client;
private NetworkStream n;
private BinaryWriter w;

// Definition for sendRadarLocation message
private string nameOfRadar;
private UInt32 typeOfRadar;
private UInt32 Alt_flag;
private UInt32 Zaltitude;
private UInt32 Range_min;
private UInt32 Range_max;
private UInt32 Azimuth;
private UInt32 HighAzimuth;

// Initiallized for SendLocation Massege
nameOfRadar = "00000000";
typeOfRadar = 7;
Alt_flag = 1;
Zaltitude = 555;
Range_min = 0;
Range_max = 0;
Azimuth = 9999;
HighAzimuth = 0;


//In button send click event :

using (client = new TcpClient("192.168.43.145", 1300))
using (n = client.GetStream())
{
    w = new BinaryWriter(n);

    w.Write(nameOfRadar);
    w.Write(typeOfRadar);

    w.Write(AzimuthStart.Text.ToString());
    w.Write(AzimuthEnd.Text.ToString());

    w.Write(Alt_flag);

    w.Write(LongRadar.Text.ToString());
    w.Write(LatRadar.Text.ToString());

    w.Write(Zaltitude);
    w.Write(Range_min);
    w.Write(Range_max);
    w.Write(Azimuth);
    w.Write(HighAzimuth);

    w.Flush();
}
```

The result is:

1. **End of stream exaption : Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.**
   As I understand from the error, it reads over than the stream have. But I sending 12 variables, and received 12 variables.
2. Another error is the textbox.Text.ToString() - it send the right string, but in the received it get a long number like : "82645173" or another number like this (even if I send the number 1).
   Thanks.

Comment: You should make specific questions; not just dump your code and hope someone wants to fix it.

Comment: The code is finishing. I got this problem in the running, I'm not dump the code and want you to fix it. It just forum for help and if you don't want or know the problem you don't must to add comment. I have problem and waiting for help. Just starting with the connection issue. Thanks.

Comment: @BenTP -1 Comments are exactly for this. Otherwise there would only be  *answer* part.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, the binary reader; "Reads primitive data types as binary values in a specific encoding."

You can't send string data and expect it to convert to primitive data types.

Comment: So, what can I do ? I want to send data that contains string and int. how to send it ?

Comment: Look at the example code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have been looked on it before but it contains files. I need to send with TCP connection between 2 application. It different

Comment: The concept of streams is that it doesn't matter what the source of the stream is (file, socket, etc.) you operate on the stream.  The source of the stream is irrelevant.

Comment: So, where I have been wrong ? By the guide it perfect.. I'm creat the network, and then the stream -> Client send, Server received. What is wrong ?

Comment: You are writing strings and reading unsigned integers.  You need to match the data types.  Look at the example ReadString matches the writing of a string literal.  ReadSingle matches the writing of a floating point literal.

Comment: @BenTP If the problem is solved, post the answer.  Some time or other *someone* will have the same or a similar problem.

Comment: The problem was that I tried to read int when it was a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you communicate over a network, you should serialize/ de-serialize data to bytes or strings, or some standard format. Why don't you try something like that:

```
//On the client:
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

// Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

//On the server:
i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
//Now you can parse this data to the types that you need.
```

Check out those two examples for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx